# How to append multiple dates using input type = date?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to get my input date field to allow the user to add multiple dates instead of just one (functioning similar to the tags metabox in wordpress -- it should also be able to remove dates), but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

How do I get this to append multiple dates?

HTML:

```
<input type="date" id="field-test2"> 
<div id="field-test"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#field-test2').on('click', function(){
        $( "#field-test" ).append( $( "#field-test2" ).val() 
    });
});
```

Comment: You have a syntax error with the unlosed append().  Also depending upon when the date field is changed, the first click may not have the new date chosen, so doing this on click might be the incorrect timing.  You might want to use the 'input' event rather than the 'click' event

Comment: You probably want a separate button "[add]" to handle adding.  Or use `.on("blur", ...`.